# TestNG paralel=classes new order every run

Tags: java, automation, testng

have such test.xml. Every time, when I start this xml, I have different order of TCs execution. It is clear how to set order without parallel, but I have to use parallel option and I want to be sure that every run I will get usual order of starting TCs.
Test1
Test2
Test3
Test4

```
<suite name="Test" verbose="1" parallel="classes">
    <test name="New test">
        <classes>
            <class name="Test1"/>
            <class name="Test2"/>
            <class name="Test3"/>
            <class name="Test4"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: add appropriate delay time in Test2 Test3 Test4 ?

Comment: Please set the preserve-order attribute to true.
And where is the thread-count attribute? How many threads are you trying to run in parallel?